# Rails atom_feed: How to add HTML tags like <h1> to the feed content?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, atom-feed

I want to structure the content of my Atom feed using headings:

```
atom_feed do |feed|
  feed.title "#{Page.model_name.human(count: :other)} - #{t('app.name')}"
  feed.updated(@pages[0].created_at) if @pages.length > 0

  @pages.each do |page|
    feed.entry(page) do |entry|
      entry.title(page.title)
      entry.content(type: 'html') do |html|
        html.h1 t('.position_in_hierarchy')
        html.p page.ancestors.reverse.map(&:title).join ': '

        html.h1 Page.human_attribute_name :lead
        html.div markdown page.lead

        html.h1 Page.human_attribute_name :content
        html.div markdown page.content
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For each of my pages, this results in the following generated XML:

```
<entry>
  <id>tag:localhost,2005:PageDecorator/1</id>
  <published>2017-02-24T18:11:26+01:00</published>
  <updated>2017-04-05T09:58:42+02:00</updated>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://localhost:3001/en/pages/1"/>
  <title>Preparation</title>
  <content type="html">
    <h1>Position in page hierarchy</h1>
    <p>Preparation</p>
    <h1>Lead</h1>
    <div>&lt;p&gt;This the lead.&lt;/p&gt;</div>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <div>&lt;p&gt;This is some content!&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;h2 id="with-a-heading"&gt;With a heading&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.example.com"&gt;And a link!&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</div>
    <h1>Notice about Atom feed</h1>
    <p>Your feed reader has downloaded version 14 of the current page, which was current at April 05, 2017 09:58. Meanwhile there could be an updated version of the page available online. Visit the original page to see the most current version!</p>
  </content>
</entry>
```

As you can see, the `html.h1` calls are rendered as plain `<h1>`. But interestingly, my feed reader Vienna doesn't display them! More interestingly, the content of `html.div`, which is markdown rendered by my custom `markdown` method, is html escaped... and this stuff is rendered by Vienna!

[image: screenshot]

The `markdown` method itself escapes HTML:

```
def markdown(string)
  PandocRuby.convert(string, to: :html).html_safe
end
```

So I'm pretty unsure now what to do to make my other HTML markup work in Vienna, too.

Comment: "As you can see, the html.h1 calls are rendered as plain <h1>" - what did you want to see instead, maybe show the desired result.

Comment: The thing is that `<h1>` isn't displayed visually like a heading in Vienna (see screenshot), while the escaped `&lt;h1&gt;` is displayed visually like a heading. I don't see what's the sense behind this. Do I have to escape all HTML, so it is interpreted by feed readers?

Comment: according to the atom spec the content needs to be escaped: https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/atom.html#text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kris pointed out in his comment, the content needs to be escaped: https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/atom.html#text

The easiest thing to do this is just rendering a partial like this:

```
entry.content(render(page), type: 'html')
```

This will render `_page.atom.slim` (or `.erb` or whatever) and automatically escape the HTML.